When is an operator invertible equivalent to a positive operator? Part 2
This question can be viewed as a follow up of
When is an operator invertible equivalent to a positive operator?
Let $P$ be a positive operator and $T,S,V$ be invertible operators such that $Q = T^*PT + S^*PS \leq P$ and $P - Q = V^*PV$. Then, is it true that $Q = W^*PW$ for some invertible operator $W$?
Note: Here also $T^*PT \leq Q \leq P$. But the assumptions on $Q$ are stronger compared to the previous question. i.e, both $P-Q$ and $Q-T^*PT$ are not just positive, but they are also in the invertible orbit of $P$ (under the conjugation action).
Thanks in advance :)

Still no, though the counterexample this time is more elaborate. Let $H = \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}^2$, $P$ be the projection onto $\oplus_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{C}^2$. Then I’ll leave it to you to check that $\{S^\ast PS\}$ where $S$ ranges over all invertible operators are exactly all positive operators with infinite-dimensional kernel and closed infinite-dimensional range. (Hint: the converse direction follows from the spectral theorem.) We also recall that, if a nonzero positive operator $Q$ admits an ONB consisting of eigenvectors, then its range is closed iff the infimum of nonzero eigenvalues is strictly positive. With this in mind, we consider, for each $n \geq 1$, the following three matrices:
$$A_n = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{n+1}{3n} & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B_n = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{n-1}{3n} & \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} \\ \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} & \frac{1}{3n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$C_n = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} \\ -\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} & 1 - \frac{1}{3n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
All these matrices are clearly self-adjoint. The eigenvalues of $A_n$ are $\frac{n+1}{3n}$ (which is bounded below by $\frac{1}{3}$ and above by $\frac{2}{3}$) and $0$. The eigenvalues of $B_n$ are $\frac{1}{3}$ and $0$. The eigenvalues of $C_n$ are $\frac{1}{3}(2 - \frac{1}{2n} \pm \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{n^2 - \frac{3}{4}})$, which are bounded below by $\frac{1}{3}(2 - \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{n^2}) \geq \frac{1}{6}$ and bounded above by $\frac{1}{3}(2 + \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{n^2}) \leq 1$. Thus, $(\oplus_{n \leq 0} 0) \bigoplus (\oplus_{n \geq 1} A_n)$ is a bounded, positive operator on $H$ with infinite-dimensional kernel and closed infinite-dimensional range, and the same holds if $A_n$ is replaced by $B_n$ or $C_n$. Thus, there exists invertible $T, S, V$ s.t.,
$$T^\ast PT = (\oplus_{n \leq 0} 0) \bigoplus (\oplus_{n \geq 1} A_n)$$
$$S^\ast PS = (\oplus_{n \leq 0} 0) \bigoplus (\oplus_{n \geq 1} B_n)$$
$$V^\ast PV = (\oplus_{n \leq 0} 0) \bigoplus (\oplus_{n \geq 1} C_n)$$
Moreover, $T^\ast PT + S^\ast PS + V^\ast PV = P$ as $A_n + B_n + C_n = 1$. Thus, $Q = T^\ast PT + S^\ast PS \leq P$ and $P - Q = V^\ast PV$. However, $Q$ cannot be written as $W^\ast PW$ for any invertible $W$. To see this, we calculate,
$$A_n + B_n = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} \\ \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{3n} & \frac{1}{3n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
which have eigenvalues $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6n} \pm \frac{1}{6n}\sqrt{4n^2 - 3}$. Thus, $Q$ has a sequence of strictly positive eigenvalues $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{6n}\sqrt{4n^2 - 3} \to 0$, so the range of $Q$ is not closed. Hence, $Q$ is not of the form $W^\ast PW$ for any invertible $W$.
